# Showing grahps in Log Analytics query

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

In application insights we can show charts:

[image]

I would like to show a graph in Log Analytics too is that possible? I dont see charts in there?

[image]

Comment: are you running query in log analytics workbooks? why not just run it in logs blade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please select a chart from `Visualization` drop-down if you run the query in `workbooks`:

[image]

Another way is that run the query directly in the `Logs blade` of azure log analytics service.